# "Use localized strings when possible"

Tags: string, localization, themes, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I read this on the criteria to submit a theme on Tumblr but I don't even know what a localized string is and couldn't figure it out from the search I did.

**What is a localized string?** Is it something you type on html, css or javascript?

Comment: pls see [https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n). you should post such questions on [http://webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localized strings are placeholders for text in various languages. They are used to abstract away translation related problems so Tumblr can provide their services in different languages.

Tumblr uses [these](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/localizing_themes) 
strings to provide programmers variables which always appear for the end user in the selected language they chose.